# How to query for strings that have apostrophes or any kind of non-alphanumeric characters

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, non-alphanumeric

I am trying to run some database queries with `SQLAlchemy`. But I am having an issue querying for strings that have apostrophes or any kind of non-alphanumeric character.

> For example: test = "I\'ve"

I used:

```
matchList = session.query(Quote).filter(Quote.quote.contains(test)).all()
```

There is 1 record in the database that contains `"I've"` as a substring. But, matchList is turning out to be an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

Full Code:

```
sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy_declarative import Base, Quote
from sqlalchemy_utils import escape_like

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///quotes.db")
Base.metadata.bind = engine
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

test = "I\'ve"
qList = session.query(Quote).filter(Quote.quote.contains(test.replace('\'', ''))).all()
print qList
```

It seems like `SQLAlchemy` doesn't handle escape sequence. Could anyone help

Comment: What about '...filter(Quote.quote.co tains(test.replace('/', '')'?

Comment: Not working, giving me an empty list []

Comment: sorry, turn slash to another side

Comment: No, that will not work.

Comment: yes, but two slashes? "\\"?

Comment: It is not returning anything :/

Comment: Can you add more to your code example?

Comment: Updated in the question.

Comment: What if you use 'ilike' instead of 'contains' (with 'replace' and without it)?

Comment: Can you copy paste row text into question?  It might that your quote in the db is a special char.

Answer (score 2):

The python string literal

```
"I\'ve"
```

Evaluates to the string

```
"I've"
```

However, you likely need an actual backslash in your database input, so try escaping the backslash instead of the single quote:

```
"I\\'ve"
```

All that said, there is probably a better way to escape queries in SQLAlchemy that I don't know about. Something like `db.find(Quote.quote == "I've")` where it does the escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, but escaping did not help because what I didn't realize was that was was being stored in the database was not the apostrophe I thought it was, but smart apostrophes instead.  For some reason the [Genius API](https://docs.genius.com/) was returning the smart apostrophes, and that is what I was adding to the database.

```
# In the database (smart apostrophe returned by Genius):
"Cat’s in the Cradle"

# What I was searching for (regular apostrophe)
"Cat's in the Cradle"
```

I think one possible solution is to replace the smart apostrophe with a regular one during the search.